# Log transformation is giving negative value

Tags: r, math

I have a vector :

```
 V<- c(0.0001000, 0.0005000, 0.1079436, 0.1862176, 0.4820801, 0.4935413, 0.5995658,
  0.6684667, 0.7942399, 0.8273733)
```

From this, I have to create another vector Y such as:

```
Y<- (log(V)+7)^1.5
```

Unfortunately, for the first two members of the V vector, it is giving me NaN. Certainly this is because the log transformation (log(V)+7) is giving negative value. How should I treat these two values? Should I use any sort of transformation before calculating Y?

Comment: if you can handle complex values then simply `(as.complex(log(V)+7))^1.5`. Otherwise, there isn't a meaning for the sqrt of a negative.

Comment: @Spätzle the vector V stands for the variable "time", which can't be complex. In that case, what should I do?

Comment: sure time can't be complex, but what about vector `Y`? what does it stand for?

Comment: @Spätzle Y is the mean of pnorm(m, mean,sd) where, "m" is another variable.

Comment: if so, I think there's nothing to do with those first 2 values. you might want to reconsider the `log` transformation, as `log: R_+ ->R` and you need some transformation that will provide `f: R_+ ->R_+`

Comment: There are many transformations to make the code work but no one is absolutely correct because we don't know your goal.

Comment: @Spätzle could you please explain a little bit more? what does log: R_+ ->R mean?

Comment: @DarrenTsai the goal is to find the "time varying mean" of pnorm(m,mean, sd). Could you please suggest me some of the transformations?

Comment: the log transformation takes non-negative real values as input and returns real values, both negative and positive. 
you need a transformation that will take your non-negative time values and will return a non-negative value that would be powered by 1.5

Comment: The goal contains the detail of your research, namely, what V is, why to log V, why to add 7 and take the 1.5th power...blah blah. Every transformation needs to have its meaning.

Comment: I can just tell you `(log(V) + max(abs(log(V)))) ^ 1.5` will make the negatives disapear but It's meaningless.

Comment: I concur to Darren: to give you a meaningful advice we need to understand the **_high-level problem_** you are trying to solve and why it requires `log`, `+7` and `^1.5` in the first place. This doesn't match any well known scenario so it looks like something custom made for your specific problem. Without such an information we can't help you.